# How to implement custom property validation without data annotations and model

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I need to build a form dynamically and also include per-property validation. I have a list of:

```
public class Field
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the form is:

```
<EditForm OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit" OnInvalidSubmit="@OnInvalidSubmit" EditContext="@editContext">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <CustomFieldValidator @ref="validator" />
    <DxFormLayout CaptionPosition="CaptionPosition.Vertical">
        @{
            foreach (var field in fields)
            {
                <DxFormLayoutItem Caption="@field.Label" ColSpanMd="6" BeginRow="true">
                    <Template Context="editContext">
                        <DxTextBox @bind-Text="@field.Value" BindValueMode="BindValueMode.OnInput" />
                        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => field.Value)" />
                    </Template>
                </DxFormLayoutItem>
            }
        }
        <DxFormLayoutItem ColSpanMd="12">
            <Template Context="editContext">
                <DxButton RenderStyle="ButtonRenderStyle.Primary" RenderStyleMode="ButtonRenderStyleMode.Contained" SubmitFormOnClick="true" Text="Send" />
            </Template>
        </DxFormLayoutItem>
    </DxFormLayout>
    <ValidationSummary />
</EditForm>
```

I have implemented custom validator as per MS Docs and the current solution works as expected with using a validation summary.

However, the `<ValidationMessage For... />` does not work at all.

How can I get per-property validation to work?

Answer (score 1):

Note this is not a ANSWER, but there's not enough room in comments to share this.

I can't see all the code, but a little explanation may help you understand your problem.
`ValidationSummary` will grab all the messages from the `ValidationMessageStore`, so your validator is writing messages.  The problem is how you are constructing the `FieldIdentifier` used by the store to tag messages when you log them to the store and then how `ValidationMessage` uses `FieldIdentifier` to pick the right message to display.

Your validator will be doing something like:

```
var fi = new FieldIdentifier(this.Model, this.FieldName);
this.ValidationMessageStore.Add(fi, this.Messages);
```

ValidationMessage is doing:

```
_fieldIdentifier = FieldIdentifier.Create(For);
```

To build a `FieldIdentifier` from `For` and

```
EditContext.GetValidationMessages(_fieldIdentifier)
```

to get the messages for `_fieldIdentifier`.

Your problem is you are using a list of fields and `FieldIdentifier` doesn't really cater for that.

Maybe you should consider a custom `ValidationMessage`.  Grab the code from [the AspNetCore Repo here](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/ValidationMessage.cs).

I'm currently working on custom validator and how to resolve this issue, but I'm not there yet with code I could share.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Like you explained, ValidationSummary displays the errors, but the ValidationMessage For seems to ignore ValidationMessageStore. ValidationMessage seems to only with DataAnnotationsValidator. Now we can make custom annotations, but that's a pretty complicated way to set a server based db lookup error.

Answer (score -1):

My be you can try like below and get a workaround!

In the View put the following code:

```
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Label)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value)
```

Then in your controller put the following code:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("Label", "Error Message for Label Property")
ModelState.AddModelError("Value", "Error Message for Value Property")
```

Comment: This is Blazor, not MVC.

Comment: Oh! yes. Thank you @Ivan-MarkDebono